# How to write VHDL testbench

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity ripplecarry4bit is
    port( a,b: in std_logic_vector (0 to 4);
          cin: in std_logic;
          s: out std_logic_vector (0 to 4);
          cout: out std_logic);
end ripplecarry4bit;

architecture RC4 of ripplecarry4bit is
    signal c: std_logic_vector (0 to 2);
    component fulladder4bit is
        port( a,b,cin: in std_logic;
              s,cout: out std_logic);
    end component;
    begin
        fa0: fulladder4bit port map(a(0), b(0), cin, s(0), c(0));
        fa1: fulladder4bit port map(a(1), b(1), c(0), s(1), c(1));
        fa2: fulladder4bit port map(a(2), b(2), c(1), s(2), c(2));
        fa3: fulladder4bit port map(a(3), b(3), c(2), s(3), cout);
end RC4;
```

I wrote this VHDL code and I'd want to test it!
Can you explain me how to write a testbench (or if you know some guide on web could you link it to me? I searched yet but I didn't find anything specifically)?

Comment: There are two pages of stuff on [my company's website](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/test_benches_part_1/). Writing the testbench is usually at least as much effort as writing the design itself. A journey of 1000 miles starts with a single step...

Comment: You're ripplecarry4bit `a`, `b` and `s` ports each have one too many elements (`0 to 4` is five 'bits' in a 4 bit adder).

Comment: "How to write VHDL testbench" is a quite general question... had to chuckle.

Comment: Funny enough, the Vivado simulation tutorial doesn't contain any VHDL testbench examples. You could look to [Xilinx Application Note 199](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp199.pdf) from ISE.

Comment: Here's an example of [self-checking testbench](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qka2geqdo0wvegs/ripplecarry4bit_tb.vhdl) for your ripplecarry4 bit adder using a reference algorithmic implementation in lieu of result vectors as in XAPP199. Note the left right order has been changed to MSB left for `a`, `b`, and `s` in your entity to keep from having to swap the order in a waveform display. IEEE binary math packages use a convention of MSB on the left as well. There's an added behavioral modeled fulladder4bit single bit full adder as well.